# regular expression to ignore file extension pattern xxx.html vs xxx.prod.html

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few directories to extract files. I only want the `.prod` files:

Example

```
src
 - dir1
   -- file1.prod.html
   -- file1.html
   -- file2.prod.html
   -- file2.html
 - dir2
-- filex.prod.html
-- filex.html
-- filen.prod.html
-- filen.html
```

I would like exclude all `.html` (but not `.prod.html`)

expected results:

```
src
     - dir1
       -- file1.prod.html
       -- file2.prod.html
     - dir2
       -- filex.prod.html
       -- filen.prod.html




   ((?!.html).prod.html$)
```

Comment: In that case, why not just check if the file name contains .prod. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match strings ending on `.prod.html` you don't need a lookahead:

```
^.+\.prod\.html$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR9NIk/1)

Answer (score 0):

I might be making this too simple, but since the base .html files do not contain .prod you could just key on that. Try: `.*\.prod.*`

Comment: `.*\.prod\..*` Requires .prod.

Comment: That matches too much as well. It will capture `cool.prod.donotmatchme.html`

Comment: You said you wanted .prod files... do you only want .prod.html?

Comment: I don't know. OP doesn't clearly specify but based on their examples this regex matches too much.

Comment: the `.*\.prod\..*` doesn't match too much if he wants all .prod files. If there are other exceptions then maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```
^((\.prod\.html)|(?!html).)*$
```